# How to add an Image to MySQL with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I'm new here and this is my first "web-project". The code you see works so far. It's possible to add text, dates etc. from my website to a MySQL database. Now I want to Upload an Image to the data set. I would like to save the image on the local server and put the direction to the database. But how?

Any ideas?

Best,
Iven

index.html:

```
...
   <input class="input-group" enctype="multipart/form-data" type="file" 
          name="event_img" id="event_img" accept="image/*" />
...
```

eventhandler.js:

```
...

$("button#insert").click(function () {

    var eventData = {

        action: "insert",

        event_name: $('#event_name').val(),
        event_location: $('#event_location').val(),
        event_date: $('#event_date').val(),
        event_time: $('#event_time').val(),
        event_weblink: $('#event_weblink').val(),
        event_text: $('#event_text').val(),
        event_genre: $("input[name='event_genre']:checked").val()

    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Blik/crud.php",
        data: eventData,

        success: function (msg) {
            var obj = $.parseJSON(msg);
            if (obj.message) {
                $("#footerfeedback").text(obj.message);
            } else {

...

                $("#footerfeedback").text(outstr);
            }
        }
    });
});

...
```

crud.php:

```
            ...


            try {
                $sql = 'INSERT INTO events SET

                event_name = :event_name, 
                event_date = :event_date,
                event_time = :event_time,
                event_location = :event_location,         
                event_text = :event_text,
                event_weblink = :event_weblink,

                event_genre = :event_genre';


                $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
                $s->bindValue(':event_name', $_POST['event_name']); 
                $s->bindValue(':event_date', $_POST['event_date']); 
                $s->bindValue(':event_time', $_POST['event_time']); 
                $s->bindValue(':event_location',$_POST['event_location']); 
                $s->bindValue(':event_text', $_POST['event_text']); 
                $s->bindValue(':event_weblink', $_POST['event_weblink']); 
                $s->bindValue(':event_genre', $_POST['event_genre']); 
             //   $s->bindValue(':event_img', $_POST[$target_file]); 

                $s->execute();


                $response = array('message' => 'insert done');
...
```

Comment: can you make this into a js-fiddle, and post a link?  I was almost inclined to do so, to help, but i only have so much time in a day.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to upload the image to your server with a separate ajax call and insert the file or its path on success to input in the form, And submit it like you are doing it already. [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23980733/jquery-ajax-file-upload-php) for more help one how to upload files using ajax. I hope it helps.

Comment: ok this makes totally sense. thank you!